# Online course that covers Unix/Linux Systems programming

Tags: system-programming

I am looking for an online course, something similar to the Berkely and Stanford Courses that covers Linux systems programming. A course which could use Stevens ( with some supplemental material covering  linux idiosyncracies ) as the text ( observe: could use not does use ).

Purpose: I've read through a large chunk of Stevens--somewhere between 1/3 and 2/3. Essentially I would like to plug in the gaps as easily as possible. A set of video lectures seems the best way. But not some youtube dweeb trying to show he can tie his Linux shoelaces. **[1]**

**[1]** Not all youtube entries are like that, but you will have to wade through a lot to get to the worthwhile ones. Unless you get lucky.

Comment: Do you care if they're free or paid for?

Comment: I'm not interested in getting Certified, just in learning the stuff. Usually the value you get for the paid for ones is the certification. Of course I'm also cheap.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @terdon I actually disagree. The lack of substantial online (or for that matter classroom) material is in fact a real tangible problem and IS definitely worth a question. I have in fact taken Prof Molay's course and have the McCusick videos (but have watched only the first video); and am still looking for more resources. This is a VERY relevant question for me, not just the OP.

Comment: @haziz the subject is very much open to discussion. I have in fact posted [a question](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2642/22222) on meta about this. Please come and post an answer if you disagree.

Answer (score 8):

#### Free

- [Openclassroom](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/HomePage.php)

  - Full courses. Short Videos. Free for everyone, stanford.edu
- [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses)

  - Education company that partners with the top universities and organizations in the world to offer courses online for anyone to take, for free.
- [MIT Open Courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm)

  - Massachusetts Institute of Technology Courses.
- [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

  - Learn to code interactively, for free.
- [Free Online Computer Science Course](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/intensive-introduction-computer-science)

  - Harvard Extension School
- [Stanford Engineering Everywhere](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courses.aspx)

  - Stanford University
- [Computer Science & Artificial Intelligence](http://www.openculture.com/freeonlinecourses)

  - 700 Free Online Courses from Top Universities (scroll down for these)
- [CodeAvengers](http://www.codeavengers.com/)

  - Interactive online courses that teach the basics of web development and computer programming (HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript).
- [MOOCs: Top 10 Sites for Free Education With Elite Universities](http://www.bdpa-detroit.org/portal/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57:moocs-top-10-sites-for-free-education-with-elite-universities&catid=29:education&Itemid=20)

  - Massive Open Online Courses - pretty extensive list.

#### Paid

- [The Certificate Program in Linux®/UNIX](http://continuinged.uml.edu/certificates/unix.cfm)

  - Umass Lowell
- [Unix/Linux Certificate](https://www.uclaextension.edu/pages/ProgramDetails.aspx?reg=CF537)

  - UCLA Extension
- [UNIX & Linux System Administration Certificate](http://extension.ucsd.edu/programs/index.cfm?vAction=certDetail&vCertificateID=230&vStudyAreaID=116)

  - UCSD Extension

Comment: Great links! BTW, in Coursera, it is possible to receive an official certificate if completed all the assignments.

Comment: @Eugene S You were able to find something on Unix Systems programming on those sites, because I couldn't.

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog You're right. I have just found few things that **I** needed myself so it got me a bit too excited and I disregarded the original.

Comment: Check out the list, I've added more URLs. LMK if these are what you're looking for, I have more but didn't want to put too much more into this answer.

Comment: Most, if not all, of these have absolutely nothing to do with Unix or Linux systems programming.

Comment: @haziz - this is what I've found so far. There are lots of resources but they're fractured and I can add more to the list, but the OP hasn't refined what he wants beyond what I initially posted and then added to. I'm not going to dump a bunch of links into an A here, that's not really the intent of the SE sites. Google can do a much better job than I, and keep it up to date!

Comment: I am not trying to be argumentative but the OP was quite explicit in asking about Unix and Linux Systems Programming and used Stevens, which is considered the "bible" regarding this topic. This is a fairly well defined topic. The OP also commented above that he did not find these links useful.

Comment: @haziz - I'm familiar with who Stevens is and the topic the OP is asking about 8-). These are the resources that I was able to find in searching the internet extensively. If you look through my backlog of A's you should note that I spend a LOT of time in doing research for the Q's I answer, so if these are the best that I could find, then there probably isn't a central clearinghouse that offers good resources related to Unix/Linux Systems programming.

Comment: @haziz - the perceived low value of these links is more an indication of the state of things on the internet wrt the topic. There just aren't a lot of "free" resources that pull everything together in the same manner that a 4 year degree will give you, when it comes to this particular knowledge domain. Most of the materials are geared to ultra specific niches such as learning Ruby, learning Linux (as an administrator) setting up MySQL, etc. etc. Hence why if you really want to learn about this particular topic, getting a formal degree would prob. be the best course of action!

Comment: I totally agree. There are very few available resources regarding this topic, which is a good reason why I think this question and the answers should remain open. Unfortunately I am personally pursuing this as an amateur (I am a masochist I guess) and can't spare 4 years for it. I did in fact take the Harvard/Molay course in 2012 and have the McCusick DVDs (unfortunately I watched only the first).

Comment: @haziz - this question will remain here w/ the A when/if it gets closed. It just won't be able to have additional A's. I totally understand the rationale, but we would never allow a person to read and then become a surgeon, so too with doing things in this knowledge domain. But I spend all my free time helping ppl here to learn more, as I am learning more, and there are special ppl that can read things and grok them, it's just that for the bulk of ppl they need to have the blueprint laid out ahead of time so that they understand how things go together at a high level.

Comment: @haziz- if this question were more specifically targeted to a narrow niche of learning system programming and I'm trying to develop a linux kernel module, that would make a huge difference in it being allowed/disallowed. The problem is it is targeting the topic at too high a level, not so much that it's linking to educational resources.

Answer (score 2):

Harvard Extension School, offers an online (and real classroom if you live in the greater Boston area) class on Unix & Linux systems programming.

[CSCI E-28 Unix/Linux Systems Programming by Prof. Bruce Molay.](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/courses/unixlinux-systems-programming/24040)

I highly recommend it, but it is not free.

Another option is a set of [videos and books by Marshall Kirk McCusick](http://www.mckusick.com/courses/) (of BSD fame) about the FreeBSD kernel. He used to give it as a classroom course with the Berkeley Extension School but is now publishing as a set of videos (again not free).

Comment: Add a link if you can.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it isn't really finite. They're doing that today, but whose to say that Prof. Bruce Molay will stop it tomorrow. So I won't DV your answer but it's not really the best way to approach answering this Q. My answer attempted to provide overarching resources where materials could be found. So your type of link should've really been just a comment!

Comment: @slm That course has run every year in spring since the early 1990s. It was previously called CSCI E-215.

Comment: and it's been offered online since?? I was just making a point that ultra specific class listings to a Q like this isn't the right way to go, that will become a un-maintainable mess and lead to a Q&A that is more opinionated than an actual resource, which isn't really in the spirit of the SE sites.