# Learning Unix with video lessons

Tags: video

Is there any web site where I can learn Linux or Unix with video lessons? Of course, there should be many of them, but I think there is one most popular like, let's say, Coursera.

Comment: What specifically do you want to learn? Your question is pretty broad. And what is Coursera?

Comment: I want to learn fundamentals, first of all.

Comment: What do you mean with fundamentals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this U&L Q&A titled: [Online course that covers Unix/Linux Systems programming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75686/online-course-that-covers-unix-linux-systems-programming/75725#75725). I provided a pretty extensive list of sites that offer videos for learning Unix.