# Places to learn linux

Tags: learning

Where can I go to learn about Linux?

I found The Linux Documentation Project but a lot of it is old and so not complete.

Any other good resources?

Comment: A lot of LDP is old but that does not mean it is out of date.  It could be, but so could something written 6 months ago.  I know that doesn't exactly help, but my point is, just because something was written 5 or 10 years ago doesn't make it worthless, and conversely, just because something was written yesterday doesn't mean it is correct.  Most things covered in the LDP are probably also discussed elsewhere, so if you search online you may find clues that help to determine it's usefulness (you may also find something better, of course).  Comparing multiple references is a good thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that will depend on what is your final goal, desktop user, programmer, system admin,.... However you can start with this tutorial http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/. Or you can take a look at this topic here [Online course that covers Unix/Linux Systems programming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75686/online-course-that-covers-unix-linux-systems-programming/75725#75725)